# Change div content if screen resolution is less than?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some floating elements to my site that won't be seen if the screen res is 1024X768 and below. So I want to give people with that screen res a different placement of that content and it will be slightly different code for the content too.

Say the people with 1024 and above will get a large square floating down the left hand side of the page and the people below will get a rectangle positioned above the main content.

There's prob some javascript projects for doing this I guess but I haven't managed to find any...

This is the content I wish to change main div id will also change.

Here is an example of something like what needs t be done.

function shareStuff() {

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
   <div id="sharepost"><div class="sharer"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="code_love" data-related="love:code">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
<div class="sharer"><a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script></span>
</div><div class="sharer"><a title="Post on Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="normal-count" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js" defer="defer"></script></div><div class="sharer"><script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=3"></script></div><span class="st_email" ></span>
</div>

} else {
  <div id="sharepost"><div class="sharer"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="horizontal" data-via="code_love" data-related="love:code">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
<div class="sharer"><a name="fb_share" type="horizontalk" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script></span>
</div><div class="sharer"><a title="Post on Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="normal-count" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js" defer="defer"></script></div><div class="sharer"><script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=3"></script></div><span class="st_email" ></span>
</div>
} }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: contents in square and in rectangle are the same? It's only a matter of positioning?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to go with fluid layouts in this case

Comment: The rectangle and square contents are completely different HTMl codes. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

please don't use javascript if not necessary, media queries can help

```
<!-- here provide css for all (also > 1024px) cases -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='allresolution.css' />

<!-- here overwrite css for small devices -->
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all and (max-width:1024px)" href='lessthan1024.css' />
```

Comment: Oh but it's not just the stylesheet it is also content on the page as the div's will hold different data depending on screen resolution. Thanks

Comment: you could put both contents in 2 different div or aside elements then show only the right one

Comment: for a matter of performance and document size you should obviously serve only the right content but at least you will avoid to retrieve contents by ajax calls making your page not accessible.

Comment: Yes the contents have different html content, different div's too and contain javascript tags which call external javascript files.

Comment: @fcalderan - how can you change the content of a div with CSS style? For 1024 screen, I need to change tittle to a shorter one and I would like to be able to implement your idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can't detect screen resolution, but you can detect the browser size:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    // code for small viewports
} else {
    // code for large viewports
}
```

This should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Do I need to put that inside script tags? Thanks

Comment: @Mark That is Javascript -- you need to put it within script tags and a `document.onready` handler.  You then need to use Javascript inside it to alter the layout of your page.  The best way would be to apply a class to the `body` element and then have two sets of CSS settings depending on the class of the `body`.

Comment: Can I put scripts inside it too? As this holds share buttons from Facebook Twitter etc which have javascript in them... Thanks.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure what you mean. You'd need to show your code to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks. Here is some of the code: <div class="sharer"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="brainy" data-related="hopes4thebest">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>

Comment: Mainly need to know if script tags like this <script type="text/javascript" src="platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script> will work ok inside of the code you showed me.

Answer (score 2):

You youd need to load a different css stylesheet for every situation, you can do this by checking the screen.width on load and on resize.

Something like this.

```
  if(screen.width==1024)
     {
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style_1024.css' />"); // this css runs in only 1024 resulation
     }
  else
    {
        document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style_other.css' />"); // for other resulatiom
    }
```

And you would need to remove the other stylesheet if the window change from one to the other.

Comment: If I add this inside the document write will it work?

<div class="sharer"><a href="twitter.com/share"; class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="brainy" data-related="hopes4thebest">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem. I mixed some of the answers above.

```
<div class="someclass" id="hidden_1" style="display:none"> Something very big for big screen</div> 
<div class="someclass" id="hidden_2" style="display:none"> small</div> 


 @media only screen and (min-width: 1450px)
{
#hidden_1 {display: block !important}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1281) and (max-width:1450)
{
#hidden_1 {display: block !important}
}

@media only screen and (min-width:981px) and (max-width:1024px)
{
#hidden_2 {display: block !important}
}
```

You only need to make sure you fill out ALL possible screens ! Otherwise there will be no text. My problem was with 1024px screen....

I tried to have one div normal and then hide it with the CSS !important, and it didn't work on chrome. I am new to computer...

Finally, I had to create one media query for (min1450px). If I put a general section of code that should be overwritten by the specific media query, this general section (with no media query) was overwriting the more specific ones. So I tacked the hidden div in a media query that would target all computers with min query @media only screen and (min-width: 1450px). Than the OS/browsers started to apply the right media query.