# How do I resolve this issue with conflicting script tags?

Tags: javascript, scripting

I've been researching this all week and am unable to resolve it myself, so I would really appreciate any help you can offer. I used HTML, JS, and CSS to cause a modal box to appear on the webpage after the video ends. However, I needed to have a different video and modal box used for mobile devices due to formatting issues. I added new HTML and CSS so that the correct video and modal box would appear only on the desktop version and mobile version.

I'm having issues with the JS, though - whichever code is listed second works, so the modal box appears after the video ends on the mobile version or the desktop version, but not both. I now understand that the scripts are in conflict, so the second one works instead of the first.

I looked for solutions to resolve the conflict, but what I found didn't work. Then I tried using an if else statement based on the screen width ([Change div content if screen resolution is less than?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145190/change-div-content-if-screen-resolution-is-less-than)), but that also didn't work.

Here are my two conflicting scripts:

**Mobile**

> window.onload=function()   {document.getElementById('mobileVideo').addEventListener('ended',  showmobileRatings); function showmobileRatings()  {document.getElementsByClassName("modalmobile")[0].style.display='block';}}

**Desktop**

> window.onload=function()    {document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', showRatings); function showRatings() {document.getElementsByClassName("modalAppear")[0].style.display='block';}}

Or see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPoqjd?editors=011

How can I combine them so they both work, whether I'm on a mobile device or desktop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do those scripts get put on the page in teh first place?

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign stuff to `window.onload`. It can only hold a single function.

Use `addEventListener` instead.

```js
addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  console.log("Function 1");
});
addEventListener('load', function(event) {
  console.log("Function 2");
});
```